# Django how to save POST into form?

Tags: python, django, forms, post, http-post

I'm trying to save the POST into my form.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
       print('!PRINT request.POST')
       print(request.POST)
       form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       print('!PRINT form')
       print(form)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
       return redirect('/')
```

returned:
!PRINT request.POST

~'title': ['Bart', 'Mat'], 'Create Match': ['Submit']}>

!PRINT form

~name="title" value="Mat" maxlength="200" required id="id_title"

~name="title1" class="errorlist" This field is required.

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
title1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**list.html**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
{%  csrf_token %}
{{ form.title }}
{{ form.title }}
<input type="submit" name="Create Match">
</form>>
```

Comment: what does your template file look like ? and the PostForm class ?

Comment: @Gers thank you for response i add code

Comment: it might just be a typo but it seems you repeated the {{ form.title }} field twice in list.html (the second should be form.title1 I guess), so no data is actually passed to form.title1

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet,

in views.py

```
def index(request):
    form = PostForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('/')

    return render(request,'path_to/html_template.html',context={'form':form})
```

in your html_template.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {%csrf_token%}
    {% form.as_p %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing values to your form, there is no data to save

Try something like this:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = name_of_your_model(
                field1=value_you_want_to_safe,
                field2=value_you_want_to_safe,
                ...
            )
            new_post.save()
        return redirect('/')
```